# Implement Google sign-in in flutter package

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-signin

I am creating a flutter package to be used by any flutter app developer. The package wants to add the functionality to sign-in using google. I don't want the app developer to take the hassle of registering their app on firebase console (or provide a `google-services.json` file), as is the case when using [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) or [google_sign_in](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in) flutter packages.

The package makes the app developer talk to a backend api after authentication from google. What are my options?

- I am fine exposing my google api-key in the package to be used specifically for this purpose.
- I am fine extending Google Sign-In functionality through an API call by providing a backend service that authenticates users with Google Sign-In and returns a token. Not exactly sure how the user will be able to provide credentials to Google.